# How to get the id tag name using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

friends

I'm writing an app. I'm creating some list items using JavaScript. Each of those items has an id, that is the code of that element in my database.

I need to take that id value to make some searches in my database. So, how can i do that?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please post your code, explain what you tried and what didn't work.

Comment: Not unclear what you are asking for but what you most probably need is   **this** in javascipt **<li onhover="somefunctionName(this.value);"</li>>**

Comment: I think that's a basic problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using jQuery:

```
$('.my-ul-class-name li').click(function() {
    alert($(this).attr('id'));
});

<ul class="my-ul-class-name">
    <li id="myId1"></li>
</ul>
```

This code is saying "Whenever you click on any LI item in the list with classname "my-ul-class-name", ALERT me the ID of the LI item.

Answer (score 1):

here's the way to select the id :

```
document.getElementById("idname");
```

You can add another attribute after it.